# MySQL "Date" comparisons

Tags: mysql, date

Can anyone explain how

```
WHERE customer_artwork_issued = '0000-00-00'
```

can return results such as

```
2006-10-18
0000-00-00
```

Why would the 2006 date show here when I am doing the above query?

Comment: What's the table structure? `SHOW CREATE TABLE name_of_table\G`

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't. You can test with:

```
SELECT CAST('2006-10-18' AS DATE) = '0000-00-00';
```

This comparison returns 0. I guess that you have multiple date columns and are looking at the wrong one.